# AngularJS SVG directive without deprecated replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I use a lot of directives to draw and manipulate a complex SVG.
Since 1.3.?? the use of "replace" in directive factories is deprecated. I wonder how I should build a valid SVG without using `replace: true` in my directives. My directives look like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('myRect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateNamespace: 'svg',
    template: '<rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="50" fill="blue" />'
  };
})
```

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/T2IQMK329AUeD1c1pD18) for an example of two SVG directives, one using `replace: true` and one not.

Comment: Something like this postcompile ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs#27469582

Comment: @AardVark71 I will try this, if there is no other solution, any `replace` is actually removed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute matching instead. From my original example I change `<my-rect-non-replace></my-rect-non-replace>` to `<g my-rect-non-replace></g>` which results in valid SVG `<g><rect /></g>`

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SpsQvjN2OgPTKxKheMx?p=preview)

If the template is more complex, I have to add closing tags to svg elements for some reasons. Otherwise the included code gets messed up.

```
<g>
<!-- Don't do this:
<line x1="-15" x2="15" y1="-25" y2="-25" />
--> 
<line x1="-15" x2="15" y1="-25" y2="-25" ></line>
<rect fill="white" width="16" height="50" x="-8" y="-25" ></rect>
<line x1="-15" x2="15" y1="25" y2="25" ></line>
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was stuck because i didn't know about templateNamespace.  I require IE11, so I am stuck with replace=true.  But that's ok.