# Angular 1.5 component vs directive ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js, angularjs-ng-transclude

i'm currently trying to figure out why my directive or my component behave different when using transclude: true.

**Navigation.hbs**

```
<my-custom-element ng-transclude>
  <div>
    <h3>Scope: {[{$ctrl.test}]}</h3>
  </div>
</my-custom-element>
```

**Directive**

```
function CustomDirective() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   controller: MyController,
   controllerAs: '$ctrl',
   transclude: true
  }
}

export function register(ngModule) {
  ngModule.directive('myCustomElement', CustomDirective);
}
```

**Component**

```
const CustomComponent = {
  controller: MyController,
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
};

export function register(ngModule) {
  ngModule.component('myCustomElement', CustomComponent);
}
```

**Controller**

```
export default class MyController {
  constructor() {
    this.test = 'this is just a teststring';
  }
}
```

**Explanation**
I've got server-side rendered handlebars templates. On the client side, I want to add some logic to my view. The idea is to take the existing view and bind a component to it, so that I can inject a controller.

My problem is, when I'm using the directive-based approach, the existing view gets transcluded, and **{[{$ctrl.test}]}** gets replaced with **this is just a teststring**.
Using the component-based approach **{[{$ctrl.test}]}** is not replaced, as if controller wasn't bound.

I'Ve read a lot about using the link function for managing scopes when transcluding, but I don't want to use a directive, and components do not have the link function.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Maybe it's nothing, but after hours of googling, I could not find any helpful resources. *Maybe I'm just googling the wrong thing.*

Comment: Can you add an example with plunker in order to see that ?

Comment: Also having this same problem...

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: Well honestlys I think I was approcahing my problem the false way. After rethinking my problem I went with an another approach - doing what I wanted to do didnt' seem to be the right way. Only thing I can help you all with is rethink what you're trying to achieve :/ Sorry guys/girls

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `$parent` to get access to component controller from transcluded part. In order to do so you should add `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` slot into your custom element template, something like:

**Component**

```
const CustomComponent = {
    controller: MyController,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
};

export function register(ngModule) {
    ngModule.component('myCustomElement', CustomComponent);
}
```

**Navigation.hbs**

```
<my-custom-element>
    <div>
        <h3>Scope: {[{ $parent.$ctrl.test }]}</h3>
    </div>
</my-custom-element>
```

Please note that [`replace: true` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195251/5498563).