# Is there any way to add a "dummy" html element to add multi-level iteration in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I often find myself in the situation where I need an ng-repeat on something that should correspond to nothing in the DOM.  For example, say I have the following object:

```
groupedHeaders = {
  'group1' : ['header1', 'header2'],
  'group2' : ['header3', 'header4', 'header5'],
  'group3' : [.....],
  ...,
  ...,
  'groupN' : [....]
}
```

I want to create a table with all of the headers.  So I want to do something like this to give me one row with one th element per header:

```
<tr>
  <dummy ng-repeat="(group, headers) in groupedHeaders">
    <th nr-repeat="header in headers">
      {{header}}
    </th>
  </dummy>
</tr>
```

So the "dummy" element just adds another "level" to my iteration (like having two for loops).

Is there any way to have an ng-repeat on an element which doesn't correspond to anything in the DOM?

If not, am I missing something basic about how to do this?  I am using Angular 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution seems to be a "dummy" element within the DOM without any logic.

If you prefix the tag with "data-", it is even HTML5 compatible.

```
<tr>
  <data-ng-repeat-dummy ng-repeat="(group, headers) in groupedHeaders">
    <th nr-repeat="header in headers">
      {{header}}
    </th>
  </data-ng-repeat-dummy>
</tr>
```

Obviously you could also create a very empty directive that does nothing, basically creating the same code. (with ng-transclude)

```
<data-ng-repeat-dummy ng-repeat="(group, headers) in groupedHeaders" ng-transclude>

angular.module('mymodule', []).directive('dataNgRepeatDummy', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true
    };
}]);
```

If you add "replace:true" to the directive, you might even get it completely out of your DOM.
However, replace:true is deprecated: [Why is replace deprecated in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs)

Alternatively, you could flatten your data in the controller if thats applicable.