# Is it possible to use express handlebars to only render a partial without a layout?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I've correctly set up express handlebars with the following directory structure:

```
views/
    layouts/
    partials/
```

**user-search-partial.html (stored in views > partials)**

```
<div id="user-search">

    <h1>Search Users</h1>

</div>
```

**render block**

```
res.render('partials/site-user-search', { layout: false });
```

Using Angular on the frontend that makes various xhr requests for partial views, I need to render just the partial above without any layout/view wrapper. I managed to achieve this by adding the 'partials' directory name in the `res.render` view name but it feels like a hack. I was wondering, is there another way of loading just a partial, perhaps by adding a partials declaration to the locals/options object (second `res.render` parameter)?

Comment: Just create a directive and use the replace property, [which is, unfortunately, deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs)

Comment: @amy-blankenship Sorry Amy, this question concerns express handlebars on the server side and not Angular on the frontend. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, why did you tag it angularjs if you're not really using angularjs as angularjs?

Comment: @amy-blankenship To give context to the issue at hand, and being part of the MEAN stack I imagined an Angular + Express developer may have encountered this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` condition. For example in default `layout.hbs`:

```
{{#if layout}}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{/if}}{{{body}}}{{#if layout}}
  </body>
</html>{{/if}}
```