# upgrading to use $onInit in Directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm in the process of upgrading from AngularJS 1.4.x to 1.7.x. The app has a lot of Directives with pre-assigned bindings (which are a no-go in 1.7.x). I'm looking for the best way to migrate with minimal changes.

Current code example:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('logo', ['ENV', 'utils',
    function main(ENV, utils) {
      return {
        template: '<div><img></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          height: '@',
          imgClass: '@',
          imgStyle: '@',
          abbr: '@',
          width: '@',
          abbrObj: '=',
          url: '='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element) {

          if (scope.abbr) scope.abbrObj = utils.getObjByAbbr(scope.abbr);
          ...
```

This obviously throws an error:
`Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'abbrObj' used with directive 'logo' is non-assignable!`

I've tried the following:

```
    scope: {
      height: '@',
      imgClass: '@',
      imgStyle: '@',
      abbr: '@',
      width: '@',
      abbrObj: '=',
      url: '='
    },
    controller: function controller() {
      // Initialize
      this.$onInit = function onInit() {
        console.log(this.abbrObj, this.abbr); // results in undefined, undefined
        if (this.abbr) this.abbrObj = utils.getObjByAbbr(this.abbr);
      };
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {
    ...
```

I don't understand why the console in the Controller is returning undefined.

I've also tried using `bindToController: true` but then the postLink function can't see the updated properties as it only has access to the `scope`.

What's the best way to use `$onInit` with minimal changes?

Comment: try adding `transclude: true` after your scope

Comment: It's advised to use one or the other, either a controller or a link method. You should still be able to use both, but the point is you don't need to. 

What is your postLink attempting to do in the example with the controller? There is a postLink lifecycle hook for controllers, too. Your controller with bindToController: true puts your bindings onto the directive's context, which you are accessing with 'this'. If you need to watch for changes in those bindings from the parent directive, you should use the lifecycle hook $onChanges. *also, change '=' to '<'. One way binding is preferred.

Comment: I also wouldn't reassign the binding within the controller/link. Seems strange to allow the passing in of that binding, then reassign it based upon if a different binding is passed in. You should use a separate variable on the controller to assign the utils.getObjByAttr result.

Comment: also, fyi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-property-deprecated-in-angularjs-directives

Comment: Finally, if this or any other directive is largely presentational and doesn't need to do major dom maniplation, you should convert it to a component, which is basically syntactic sugar for a directive with specific recommended configuration.

Comment: @PietroNadalini `transclude: true` does not help. Still throws `undefined` in the `postLink` function.

Comment: @DevinFields I'm open to not using the controller. How do you bypass the `$onInit` requirement for preassigned bindings using just the `postLink` function? While this particular example might be fixed easier by using a separate variable, other parts of the code base would require a larger rewrite to handle that. Is that going to be necessary?

Comment: @DevinFields I'm aware of the deprecation of `replace`. That's an easy fix though.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary or not because I can't see the entire code. I personally would prefer using the controller in combination with lifecycle hooks, especially in this scenario (this directive looks presentational to me, prime component material)

Comment: This directive is probably pretty presentational, but others aren't and they have the same problem. What lifecycle hooks would be useful here?

Comment: I like this blog about it: https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks

Also, no matter what link method you use, you should have access to the controller through the fourth argument, I believe? I always mix up the order. I personally don't like mixing implementations of controller and links, but if you wanted a quick fix, you might be able to do what you want inside your postLink method by accessing the ctrl.

Comment: Honestly, though, if all your directives have an issue, it seems more like a design flaw that eventually needs to be addressed.

Comment: Oh it will be eventually. I was just looking to upgrade to the LTS of AngularJS for now.

Comment: if you want to get it working change preassigned bindings settings. If you want this to look nice -- rewrite everything to components... Btw, not sure why you prefer link to controller in 1.4.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov AngularJS 1.7.x deprecated preassigned bindings completely. I guess I could use 1.6.x instead, but that feels incomplete. I inherited this code base, so no idea on why. But way too much to change for a simple upgrade.