# AngularJS directive with isolate scope, ng-repeat, and controllerAs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
function directive() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-repeat="x in j.array" ng-click="j.set(x)">{{x}}</button>',
    replace: true,
    //scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      array: '=',
      answer: '='
    },
    controller: function() {
      var j = this;
      j.set = function(data) {
        j.answer = data;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'j'
  };
}
```

When I uncomment scope and create an isolate scope the directive no longer works. I'm trying to determine why.
Normally I still have access to the controllerAs in an `ng-repeat`, in this example when I lose it it's still available on `$parent.j`. I think there are 3 solutions.

Solution 1 is to leave it not in isolate scope.
Solution 2 would be to convert every reference to `j` inside the repeat to `$parent.j`.
Solution 3 is that there is some way to use `j` without having to use `$parent` that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is `replace` property deprecated in AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-property-deprecated-in-angularjs-directives/35545445#35545445).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be to do with the `replace: true`.  If you wrap the `button` in a `div`, it seems to work!  I've made a little Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/h6toiszx5NZ9AGcQHikK?p=preview) to demonstrate.